# Ionic Use Vertical Scroll not working on Horizontal scroll in Android 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create the layout having Multiple list of Horizontal scrollable images. Please check this pen :

[Horizontal Scroll inside vertical Scroll](http://codepen.io/anwar069/pen/mEKJpN)

In the above layout both Horizontal and Vertical layout is not working at the same time.

when we click and Hold the `Ion Header` Component, the Vertical scroll is working, however if we click on image inside `Ion-Scroll` the vertical scroll is not working.

I googled the issue and came across the `overflow-scroll` option which allows us to use native scrolling.

When I am setting `overflow-scroll=true` only vertical scroll is working, whereas if `overflow-scroll=false` only horizontal is working.

Using `overflow-scroll=true` do the job in web browser and both scroll works properly but when application is run on android device only Vertical scroll is working.

Is there a way to make both scroll work fluently across all devices.

please find the code below:

HTML:

```
            <html ng-app="ionicApp">

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

            <title>{{myTitle}}</title>

            <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/js/ionic.bundle.js">
            </script>
        </head>

        <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                <h1 class="title">{{myTitle}}</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>

             <ion-content>

                <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">

                    <h3 class="title ">Header 1</h3>
                </div>
                <ion-scroll direction="x">
                    <div class="row">

                        <ion-item class="card  card col col-33 margin-1 nopad" ng-repeat="img in imgName">
                            <!-- <div class="item item-divider accentback">

                            </div>-->
                            <div class="item item-image">
                                <img class="full-image" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item item-divider text-center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">
                                <h4>Image {{img}} </h4>
                            </div>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>

          <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">

                    <h3 class="title ">Header 2</h3>
                </div>
                <ion-scroll direction="x" overflow-scroll="false">
                    <div class="row">

                        <ion-item class="card  card col col-33 margin-1 nopad" ng-repeat="img in imgName">
                            <!-- <div class="item item-divider accentback">

                            </div>-->
                            <div class="item item-image">
                                <img class="full-image" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item item-divider text-center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">
                                <h4>Image {{img}} </h4>
                            </div>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>
                 <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">

                    <h3 class="title ">Header 3</h3>
                </div>
                <ion-scroll direction="x" overflow-scroll="false">
                    <div class="row">

                        <ion-item class="card  card col col-33 margin-1 nopad" ng-repeat="img in imgName">
                            <!-- <div class="item item-divider accentback">

                            </div>-->
                            <div class="item item-image">
                                <img class="full-image" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item item-divider text-center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">
                                <h4>Image {{img}} </h4>
                            </div>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>
         <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">

                    <h3 class="title ">Header 4</h3>
                </div>
                <ion-scroll direction="x" overflow-scroll="false">
                    <div class="row">

                        <ion-item class="card  card col col-33 margin-1 nopad" ng-repeat="img in imgName">
                            <!-- <div class="item item-divider accentback">

                            </div>-->
                            <div class="item item-image">
                                <img class="full-image" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item item-divider text-center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">
                                <h4>Image {{img}} </h4>
                            </div>
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>
            </ion-content>

        </body>

        </html>
```

CSS:

```
        body {
      cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
    }
```

JS:

```
        angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myTitle = 'ION Image Gallery';
      $scope.imgName=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];


    });
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. Can you test it again after putting on-drag="" on the element. This worked for me.

Comment: Hi @KBeckers, tried adding on-dra om my image element, its still not working. Have updated the pen here [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqvpoa?editors=1000)